# Entities cannot be mapped properly via hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Invoice entity which contains another entity - Counterparty and a list of another entities - Items. While setting up relations between list of items and invoice, there were no problems. However, when I try to set up a similar relation between invoice entity and counterparty entity, I get an error:

`@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on pl.coderstrust.model.Invoice.counterparty references an unknown entity: pl.coderstrust.model.counterparty.Counterparty`

This is my invoice, which expects to contain only one counterparty and a list of items.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice implements Comparable<Invoice>, Serializable {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "invoice_id")
      private int id;

      @Column(name = "date")
      private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

      @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
          CascadeType.REFRESH})
      @JoinColumn(name = "nip")
      private Counterparty counterparty;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
      @JsonBackReference
      private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is my item entity, which can be related to one invoice:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "item_id")
  private int id;
  private String description;
  private int numberOfItems;
  private BigDecimal amount;
  private BigDecimal vatAmount;

  @JoinColumn(name = "vat_code")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
  private Vat vat;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "invoice_id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
      CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.REFRESH})
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Invoice invoice;
```

This is my counterparty, which is supposed to be related to many invoices:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "counterparties")
public class Counterparty implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "nip")
  private String nip;
  private String companyName;
  private String phoneNumber;
  private String bankName;
  private String bankNumber;
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "counterparty", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "counterparty", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.MERGE,
      CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
  private List<Invoice> invoices;
```

What is wrong with invoice-counterparty relations?

Comment: Please post the imports of Counterparty.

Answer (score 0):

That Hibernate error is usually thrown when the class is not added to the hibernate configuration. Hibernate needs to be told all of the classes that serve as entities before it can use them.

How do you make your classes known to Hibernate? I.e. either by adding the class to the Configuration object:

```
configuration.addClass(Counterparty.class);
```

or by adding the class into a package that is scanned for entities when you are using Spring?

On another note: there seems to be something odd with the Item class perhaps? It specifies a OneToOne relation to Invoice; should this not be a ManyToOne (meaning that a single invoice can have 0 or more Items)?

Comment: it's being scanned from the base package provided in SpringBootApplication annotation